# Undefined offset: 2 inserting two files in a single row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting trouble inserting multiple files using Array in PHP.

```
$applications=$_FILES['applications']['name'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($applications); $i++)
{
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['applications']['tmp_name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "ujuri_admin/uploads/applications/$applications[$i]");
}

$send_data="INSERT INTO table (application[],date_now) VALUES ('$applications[$i]', NOW())";
```

Comment: `(application[],date_now)` <= is your table column really called `application[]`?

Comment: My column name is application

Comment: There's nothing about this that would work. Please check all the values before you're trying to insert the data. MySQL doesn't have any concepts of arrays so adding `[]` won''t work. The error comes from the fact that you're using `$i` after the for-loop (where it is one greater than the count). I would suggest reading up on MySQL and on how arrays work in PHP.

Comment: I removed [ ] and inserted files again. Files get moved in a folder but the row on a database is empty.

Comment: Here's a demo of what you're doing: https://3v4l.org/9tA0c and why you get an undefined index after the for loop.

Comment: try inside the for loop $send_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run your query inside the `for` loop with the current correct value of `$applications[$i]`. Your code should look something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (application, date_now) VALUES (?, NOW())');
for($i = 0; $i < count($applications); $i++)
{
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['applications']['tmp_name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "ujuri_admin/uploads/applications/$applications[$i]");
    $stmt->execute(array($applications[$i]));
}
$stmt->close();
```

(Assuming `$db` is a [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instance)